# CCSpine by cocos2d-objc-ext not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3, cocos2d-swift

I am trying to use CCSpine in my cocos2d-swift V3.3 project, there is a issue:
not found CCDictionary.h 
Where is the CCDictionary.h? Dose it in a low version of coco2d-iphone?But I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the same github [repo](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc-ext/tree/master/Extensions/CCDictionary).  Simply copy `CCDictionary.{m,h}` to your project, along with any other extension files you want to use.